# Can iPhone work with Bose dock and a Bluetooth speaker at the same time

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, speakers, headphones

I have a Bose docking station and was thinking of buying a wireless bluetooth Bose speaker as well for the living room

If I play my iPhone on the docking station in the kitchen, will the blootooth still work to play the portable speaker in the living room?

so music is being played in both rooms simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

No - the iPhone will only send audio to one of the two, with the physical speaker it is attached to being the preference.

You could possibly have the physical speaker output sound and send it to the Bose wireless but that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want now in 2015 there's an extra step that allows you to send audio to multiple devices through your macbook.

http://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2012/02/12/send-audio-from-ios-to-multiple-speakers-with-airfoil/

Meaning iPhone to mac, mac to multiple devices.

Comment: Hi, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: ahh I see. thank you for the clarification. I'm still new here. :S